# Using helpers from within express-handlebars to return HTML formatted code

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, templating

In `server.js` I have something like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var exphbs = require('express-handlebars');

var app = new express();

var handlebars = require('./helpers.js')(exphbs);

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

app.engine('.hbs', handlebars.engine);


app.set('view engine', '.hbs');

app.set ('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));

app.get('/', function(req,res){
    res.render('home', {
        title: 'Express App with Handlebars templates',
        content: 'This is some content',
        persons: [
            { 
                name: 'branchito', 
                instrument: 'guitar',
            },
            { 
                name: 'joe', 
                instrument: 'flute',
            },
        ]
    });
});



app.listen(app.get( 'port' ), function(){
    console.log('Server started on port ' + app.get('port'));
})
```

And then in my `helpers.js` file:

```
function hbsHelpers(hbs) {
  return hbs.create({
    helpers: { // This was missing
      inc: function(value, options) {
        console.log('reading it');
        return parseInt(value) + 1;
      },
      strong: function(text) {
          return '<strong>' + text + '</strong>';
      }

      // More helpers...
    }

  });
}

module.exports = hbsHelpers;
```

But then the output generated by `strong` helper renders that as a `<strong>...</strong>`.. How would I go to have that string unescaped, I know there is `Handlebars.SafeString()` but don't know how to use it from this express-handlebars instance..

Answer (score 3):

To output raw HTML instead of escaped HTML use three curly braces instead of two.

For example:

```
{{{strong}}}
```

Will output the raw HTML from the helper:

```
strong: function(text) {
  return '<strong>' + text + '</strong>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I am understanding it right and probably a little bit too late, but I had the same (or at least a similar issue):

When I wanted to show my content with {{ var }} and var was e.g.

```html
<strong>somevar</strong>
```

I had the problem that it was rendered as

```html
&lt;strong&gt;somevar&lt;/strong&gt;
```

My workaround was that the variable wasn't rendered through the default Handlebars renderer, but creating a function doing it for you:

```javascript
var hbs = exphbs.create({
    /* ... */
    helpers: {
        raw: function (a) { return a; },
    }
});
```

And in my .handlebars file I did the following:

```html
<p>{{#raw var}}{{/raw}}</p>
```

So, it's basically the same as you did. I tried your code as well, and it worked for me. Probably you're not calling it right in handlebars file?